# plotting glmer model with sjPlot

Tags: r, plot, lme4, mixed-models

```
df <- data.frame(C=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8), 
                 Y=c("F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F",
                     "M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M"), 
                 B=c(1,1,3,2,5,3,6,7,2,1,2,4,3,2,3,6,8,6,5,8,5,7,4,8,7,8,2,9,7,7,6,7))

m <- glmer(Y ~ B + (1|C), data=df, family=binomial())

plot_model(m)
```

I was hoping to obtain a similar probability curve plot as shown [here](https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/visualizing-generalized-linear-mixed-effects-models-part-2-rstats-lme4/).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Which probability curve plot?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I believe others are doing so because you're not showing much "research effort".  It's good that you've included some data and model-fitting code, but it would be even better if you showed an attempt to solve the problem yourself - at present it reads a bit like "please write the code for  me"

Comment: does https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_marginal_effects.html help?

Comment: @locus Did you read that webpage? Not sure why the answer is not just: `sjp.glmer(m, type = "fe.pc")`

Comment: @BenBolker: I played around with the plot_model arguments but I could never get the desired result. The function sjp.glmer has been replaced by plot_model and I couldn't figure out what the equivalent options were. The link you sent is helpful.

Comment: @42- because sjp.glmer function doesn't exist anymore - it was replaced by plot_model and the arguments are different.

Comment: Yes, BenBolker's link is going to be most helpful since `sjPlot` has changed a lot since the original blogpost you linked to. I think you want something like `plot_model(m, type = "pred", terms = "B")`, but please edit the question to be more specific if that's not it.

Comment: I suppose the fact that the page is dated "18. November 2014" might give you pause" about the possibility that the sjPlot package might have changed in the last 5 years. Both the prior and current versions of that package do not have a `sjp.glmer` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one fixed effect covariate (`$B`), so after reading the help page for `plot_model`, and comparing to the out-of-date material you offered. this seems to deliver the requested plot:

```
> plot_model(m, type = "pred")
$B
```

[image]

After stumbling around trying to get the most current version of sjPlot and all of the current versions of its dependencies from Github, and then reading the current help page and testing out the code above, I now see that @Marius already posted this. Oh well. If he wants to an answer, I will delete.

Comment: the last part of your answer looks more like a comment than part of an answer ...

Comment: It was in part a warning that installing sjPlot was somewhat a hassle with quite a few dependencies that did not get installed on the first second or even third go rounds, as well as a suggestion that Marius might want to post his own approach, since he might well have more experience with this package than do I.